# Insert of records into SQL Server is slow whereas select is quicker

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to improve the performance of insert in SQL Server.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GroupCustomerAccountProductRebates]([GroupId],[GroupName],[ProductId],[ManufacturerProductCode],[ProductDescription],[CustomerAccountId],[CustomerAccountNo],[CustomerAccountName],[RebatePercentage],[DatePeriodId])
    SELECT GroupId, GroupName, ProductId, ManufacturerProductCode, ProductDescription, CustomerAccountId, CustomerAccountNo, CustomerAccountName, SUM(CAST(RebatePercentage AS decimal(18,2))) AS RebatePercentage, @DatePeriod
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountFlatRateProductBrandRebatesByProduct] (NULL)

         UNION

         SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountGroupInheritedFlatRateProductBrandRebatesByProduct] (NULL)
        
         UNION
        
         SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountFlatRateProductRebatesByProduct] (NULL)

         UNION 
        
         SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountGroupInheritedFlatRateProductRebatesByProduct] (NULL)

         UNION 

         SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountTieredRebatesByProduct2] (NULL,@DatePeriod)

         UNION
        
         SELECT * 
         FROM [dbo].[fnGetCustomerAccountGroupInheritedTieredRebatesByProduct2] (NULL,@DatePeriod)
    ) x
    GROUP BY 
        GroupId, GroupName, ProductId, ManufacturerProductCode, ProductDescription, CustomerAccountId, CustomerAccountNo, CustomerAccountName
    ORDER BY 
        CustomerAccountName, ProductDescription
```

This is my query.

The `SELECT` query takes around 36 seconds for those 820,000 rows, but running with insert query takes 3 minutes for the execution.

Below link is the execution plan :
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1zcWas8c

Comment: The cost is in the query, not the INSERT.  The SELECT is getting a different plan.  Do you really need to de-duplicate the results before grouping them?  That's what UNION does.  UNION ALL simply concatenates the results.

Comment: The timings in the plan show that the `SELECT` part (subtree from stream aggregate down) takes 30 seconds and the insert takes another 1 min 10 seconds on top of that. For the FK validation and index maintenance

Comment: Any way to improve the insert part ? I want to use union since I want to remove the duplicates